# Is there a different way to convert to hexadecimal?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write some information to a special device that requires me to encode the string and I quote " an even number of bytes to write (1-32, base 10) "

The example string provided "DE AD BE EF CA FE" (works).
I have converted my string to decimal and from decimal to hexadecimal.

```
string TextToConvert = "Test Andrei";
            TextToConvert=ConvertStringToHex(TextToConvert, Encoding.UTF8);

            List<char> Chars = TextToConvert.ToCharArray().ToList();
            string CharValue = "";
            string secondHexConvert = "";
            foreach(char c in Chars)
            {
                CharValue+=Convert.ToInt32(c);
                secondHexConvert+=Convert.ToString(c, 16)+" ";
            }
            string hexValue = String.Format("{0:X}", CharValue)+" ";
```

I have found on internet a tool that converts to hexadecimal that works. The problem is that I can't figure what type of encoding is that. The site is this: https://codebeautify.org/decimal-hex-converter
from decimal "841011151163265110100114101105" to hex = "a9d741e82c990000000000000"

Answer (score 2):

To convert such a big integer to a hexadecimal string, use the aptly named [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.8) type:

```
var num = BigInteger.Parse("841011151163265110100114101105");
string hex = num.ToString("X");
Console.WriteLine(hex);
```

will output:

```
0A9D741E82C98FC6A137B75371
```

but here's a snag, the output you showed in your question is somewhat different, let me show it together with what the code above produces:

```
0A9D741E82C98FC6A137B75371
 a9d741e82c990000000000000
```

As you can see, the numbers start the same but your example then ends up with lots of zeroes.

The only way I understand this could happen is that they're in fact not using a type that can hold that many significant digits, so you get a rounding error.

Many of the dynamic programming languages allows you to use floating point numbers and integers interchangeably, I guess this is what happened, a floating point type that can only hold 17-18 significant digits or some such was used, and you lost precision. .NET, however, doesn't have built-in support for converting floating point types to hexadecimal.

You can see that .NET produces the exact value by converting back:

```
Console.WriteLine(BigInteger.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
```

outputs:

```
841011151163265110100114101105
```

**In other words, I'm not sure you *can* get the exact same results in .NET.**

**Corollary:** Don't use that site for this kind of conversion!

Comment: Your conclusion seems accurate, since even that site's hex->decimal converter doesn't return the same value as input into the decimal->hex converter.

Comment: I have tested your answer. With that encoding I receive an error saying "Number of data bytes must be even", I can't imagine what is referring to ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to convert a string to hexadecimal:

```
     public static string ConvertStringToHex(String input, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
    {
         Byte[] stringBytes = encoding.GetBytes(input);
        StringBuilder sbBytes = new StringBuilder(stringBytes.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in stringBytes)
         {
             sbBytes.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);
        }
        return sbBytes.ToString();
    }
```

And you just call it using:

```
string testString = "11111111";
string hex = ConvertStringToHex(testString, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);
```

Comment: OP isn't converting an arbitrary string to hexadecimal: OP is converting a big number stored in a string to hexadecimal. To that effect, your code will result in "10" becoming "3130" whereas OP would expect "A".